Deploying a .NET Aspire project's apphost to a docker container
I am trying to deploy a .NET Aspire project to a docker container. I used docker init to create a dockerfile and a docker compose but when I try running docker compose up --build it says it didn't find an Aspire workload installed. I tried adding a command to install the workload, but now when I run the publish command it doesn't create the output folder.
Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

# Want to help us make this template better? Share your feedback here: https://forms.gle/ybq9Krt8jtBL3iCk7

################################################################################

# Learn about building .NET container images:
# https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/README.md

# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build

COPY . /source

WORKDIR /source/Catalog.AppHost

# This is the architecture you’re building for, which is passed in by the builder.
# Placing it here allows the previous steps to be cached across architectures.
ARG TARGETARCH

# Build the application.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.nuget/packages so that subsequent builds don't have to re-download packages.
# If TARGETARCH is "amd64", replace it with "x64" - "x64" is .NET's canonical name for this and "amd64" doesn't
#   work in .NET 6.0.
RUN dotnet workload install aspire && \
    dotnet restore
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages \
    dotnet publish -a ${TARGETARCH/amd64/x64} -c Debug --use-current-runtime --self-contained false -o /app && \
    ls -al && ls ../ -al && ls ../../ -al

# If you need to enable globalization and time zones:
# https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/enable-globalization.md
################################################################################
# Create a new stage for running the application that contains the minimal
# runtime dependencies for the application. This often uses a different base
# image from the build stage where the necessary files are copied from the build
# stage.
#
# The example below uses an aspnet alpine image as the foundation for running the app.
# It will also use whatever happens to be the most recent version of that tag when you
# build your Dockerfile. If reproducability is important, consider using a more specific
# version (e.g., aspnet:7.0.10-alpine-3.18),
# or SHA (e.g., mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet@sha256:f3d99f54d504a21d38e4cc2f13ff47d67235efeeb85c109d3d1ff1808b38d034).
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS final
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything needed to run the app from the "build" stage.
COPY --from=build /app .

# Switch to a non-privileged user (defined in the base image) that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
# and https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/discussions/4764
USER $APP_UID

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.AppHost.dll"]

docker-compose
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: final
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

The error:
docker compose up --build
[+] Building 4.1s (16/16) FINISHED                                                                                                            docker:desktop-linux
 => [server internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.80kB                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [server] resolve image config for docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                            1.0s
 => [server auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [server] docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:fe40cf4e92cd0c467be2cfc30657a680ae2398318afd50b0c80585784c604f28                      0.0s
 => [server internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine                                                                               0.4s
 => [server internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine                                                                            0.4s
 => [server internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 647B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [server internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.73kB                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [server build 1/5] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine@sha256:6e8997576d16a6d7b4e6ba7ac0956d3ae46cb7a376581c40eabd20fbc5c28b8d                   0.0s
 => [server final 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine@sha256:e22d879fb9a0fba3b2a6b15c88f005192c239e189061534c86643347b4630140                0.0s
 => CACHED [server build 2/5] COPY . /source                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [server build 3/5] WORKDIR /source/Catalog.AppHost                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [server build 4/5] RUN dotnet workload install aspire &&     dotnet restore                                                                        0.0s
 => [server build 5/5] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=nuget,target=/root/.nuget/packages     dotnet publish -a x64 -c Testing --use-current-runtime --self-contai  2.1s
 => CACHED [server final 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [server final 3/3] COPY --from=build /app .                                                                                                         0.0s
------
 > [server final 3/3] COPY --from=build /app .:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref b9d56e54-9eee-48c5-b9a6-71b47c1d6335::lymdtg8e61phx9dtukafwjrl7: "/app": not found

I tried checking to see if a folder is actually created but if I run ls on all the directories that could contain it, it doesn't appear anywhere.

Why are you running the apphost in a container?

I used aspirate to create a docker compose file of my aspire solution.
Install aspirate
dotnet tool install -g aspirate

then to generate the compose file, cd into the AppHost project folder and execute the following.
aspirate generate --output-format compose

That will create a docker compose file in the subfolder aspirate-output in the AppHost project folder. You can then tweak it as needed.

Is it work for Aspire  9.0 ?
